# display only 8 connected blobs in binary image

Tags: c#, aforge

I have used blobcounter class in Aforge to extract blobs by giving min height and min width of blob. Now I want to display a binary image with only 8 conncted blobs  plotted on them (only good blobs in white plotted on black background) .What should I do for that

```
  BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter(); 
blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
 blobCounter.MinWidth = minWidth; 
blobCounter.MinHeight = minHeight; 
blobCounter.MaxWidth = maxWidth;
 blobCounter.MaxHeight = maxHeight; 
blobCounter.CoupledSizeFiltering = true; 
blobCounter.ProcessImage(image); 
Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @alpine Post your code in your question, and delete it as comment. Do not clutter the comments with things that should be in the question.

Comment: ok. i have done that